# Azure App Service losing incoming Requests

Tags: azure, httprequest, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service hosting a web service (2 instances) with asp.net 4.7.1 MVC Web API and is consumed by multiple vendors across the U.S., either in Azure, AWS, or on premises.

It currently handles around 18K requests a day, but occasionally (1,2,3) times a day I'll get an error notification from a vendor that a request timed out.  Sometimes it's just 1 vendor, sometimes it's multiple vendors at the same time (within a minute or two).

After the issues occur, they magically go away just as quickly.  No restarts, or anything, the service just works fine again.  Sometimes the failures occur in a bunch.  Like 3 fails within a few minutes, other times just once, even during peak times.  I've found no pattern at all.  It's happened during peak traffic, and also when there was virtually none at all.

Here's the real issue:  If I check our own logs, and the IIS logs, and the application insight logs there is no evidence at all that the request(s) came through.  It's as if they were completely lost before reaching us.

If this came from just 1 vendor, I'd blame it on them, and move on.  But, many times this has occurred to multiple vendors at the exact same time.  Vendors on completely different coasts, running totally different products.

CPU, RAM, Disk, HTTP queue length, TCP Connections, and every other metric I know of all look good.

The actual requests that fail vary, but none are resource intensive.

Please, anyone have any ideas of what the issue might be?

Comment: Since you have already investigated the logs so it's difficult to figure out. Have you investigated your response time during this issue ? If a request made your way and you are processing it while client could timeout if it's taking too long but at your end you won't see that since you sent back the response regardless of how long it took , but client won't pick it up since it's already timed out. Also did you check for any locks or race conditions ?

Comment: @Imran  around the time that the issues occur, no noticable changes to response times, locks or other conditions (I looked for those first).  Doesnt mean they aren't there, but haven't been able to find them.   Interesting that while some requests get 'lost', others run just fine.  That could also be because there are at least 2 instances running at all times.

Comment: Do you have any middle ware , request filtering , authentication/Authorisation in place i am sure you have already investigated that too? Another way If you are running App service you can run performance test during off peak time. Fill the user load and run it for couple of mins and then investigate the pattern, this way you can investigate from user perspective and If you find requests getting failed you can investigate that easily.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=vsts

Comment: @Imran  no middleware, we have auth in place for some services, but the ones having issues are open, so nothing would block them from coming through.

I've resisted the load test just for the hit on the servers, but I might need to go there.  We do have a 'Pinger' service that I created that hits the services every 5 minutes and logs the results.  Thus far, none have ever timed out.

Comment: You mentioned App insight already set , Make sure application insight is embedded in the application and use any performance load testing tool (Jmeter is another option) and run if for couple of minutes. I would be interested to know about the failed requests.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help others:  We did find a solution for it eventually.  We were using the built in SSL Certificate: *.azurewebsites.net.  There wasn't really a reason to have a custom domain.   However, we did eventually get a custom domain and enabled IP SSL for that domain.  When you do that it'll allocate a static IP to the website.  Once we did that, the problem went away immediately. So, something about DNS?  Routing?  I don't really know for sure. But, it did fix the issue.

Comment: Agreed, it's probably a DNS issue.  When I read this, I took a coffee break and when I got back everything was working again.   DNS updates can take 10-20 minutes to propagate, and if you stop and start an app service like I did, it's bets to be aware that you're service will probably return 502 errors for a few minutes.